# Guard, round, sticky bits (floating point)

Tags: floating-point, rounding

I don't understand what is the meaning of guard, round and sticky bits. I have an example: if we add 3.25+30 (3 bit mantissa) we get 32 because grs=011.
I was trying to solve it but all I have managed to do is this:
30=1.111*2^4
3.25=0.001101*2^4
and if I add up the numbers the result is 1.0000101*2^5, which means g=0 r=1 s=1. The problem is now that I can't figure out why is the correct answer 32.

Comment: The guard, round and sticky bits are used to determine if you must round, i.e. if you must remove some trailing bits from a value. The first two **of the bits to be removed** are the guard and round bit, respectively. The sticky bit is simply 1 if any of the other bits is 1. The combination of these three bits governs if the value of the bits that remain must be incremented by 1 or not.

Comment: See the **on Rounding** part of the following text: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~markhill/cs354/Fall2008/notes/flpt.apprec.html

Comment: FWIW, what do you mean with "3 bit mantissa"? And **you don't have to round** that at all. Both are exactly representable in any of the know IEEE-754 floating point formats, and so is the result.

Comment: “3 bit mantissa” means a significand with three bits. The questioner is a student working on a sample problem using three-bit significands. The IEEE 754 floating-point formats are irrelevant to this.

Answer (score 2):

Guard, round, and sticky bits of 0, 1, 1 tell you that the “residue bits” (by which I mean the bits starting just below the point where we are going to round) are .01*xxx…*, where *xxx…* is not known but contains at least one 1 bit. Thus, the “residue” portion is more than ¼ ULP (is .01 plus something positive) but less than ½ ULP (is less than .100…).

If you are rounding to nearest, you would round down, since the “residue” portion is less than ½ ULP.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the above [notes_1](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Emarkhill/cs354/Fall2008/notes/flpt.apprec.html) referenced by "Rudy Velthuis". More specifically, `30=1.111*2^4` implies rounding to 0.001, so `1.0000101*2^5` rounds to `1.000*2^5=32` (Since you doesn't specify how you get the right answer 32, here I take "rounding to nearest").

---

Since your question title is more general, here I also describe about why using 3 extra bits **instead of** 2 bits or less?

1. description of how 3 bits are got can be seen from the above notes_1. You can find that the guard bit and the round bit are similar (i.e. manipulate them by just shifting), while the sticky bit "sticks" without being shifted off.

   > If a value of 1 ever is shifted into the sticky bit position, that sticky bit **remains** a 1 ("sticks" at 1), despite further shifts.
2. why not using only the pair (Round,Sticky) or the pair (Guard,Sticky)? (Here the Round bit and the Guard bit are manipulated with the same operation (only shifting without sticking), so I put them together)

   the [handout_1](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Edavid/courses/cs552/S12/handouts/guardbits.pdf) from another SO question's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45662113/guard-round-sticky-bits-floating-point#comment78287551_45662113) shows one useful example with failure where the only one sticky bit "1" (highlighted below) after the **normalization** operation can't decide the rounding results **if using "round to nearest"**:

   > 1.000 00 x 2^5
   >
   > - 0.000 11 x 2^5 Round is 1, Sticky is 1
   >
   > 0.111 01 x 2^5 Need to shift left to normalize, must use Round bit
   >
   > 1.110 **1** x 2^4 Can’t round using Sticky, since **can’t tell if >/=/< 1/2 ULP**
3. why not using the pair (Guard,Round)?
   This is also implied in the answer by Eric Postpischil.

   - From "chapter 3.5 Floating Point" in the book Computer Organization and Design: The Hardware/Software Interface RISCV 2rd edition by David A. Patterson:

     > Suppose we added $5.01 × 10^{−1} to 2.34 × 10^2$ in the example above. Even with guard and round, we would be adding **0.0050** to 2.34, with a sum of 2.3450. The sticky bit would be set, since there are nonzero bits to the right. Without the sticky bit to **remember whether any 1s were shifted off**, we would assume the number is equal to 2.345000 ... 00 and **round to the nearest even** of 2.34. With the sticky bit to remember that the number is **larger than** 2.345000 ... 00, we round instead to 2.35.

     Here `0.0050` with the pair (Guard,Round) instead of `0.00501` with the sticky bit `1` concatenated will cause the different results with "round to the nearest even".